# How to copy Windows 10 system files in Linux?

Tags: windows, file-copy

I am trying to switch from one hard drive to another.  So I decided to boot in Linux, hook both hard drives up, and copy all files from one hard drive to the other.

However, when I try to copy protected Windows-10 files, such as C:\Windows\explorer.exe or C:\Windows\notepad.exe, I get the following error:

```
cp: cannot access 'explorer.exe': Input/output error
```

The same happens regardless of the command that I run on the file -- even `ls`, or including `sudo`.  Clearly, the file is present, since Windows boots normally.  Also, the hard drive is not damaged.

How do I bypass this error, and copy these Windows files onto the new hard drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you just copy files from one NTFS partition to another there's a high chance your Windows won't boot at all. You'll need to use `ntfsclone` for that.
2. Speaking of your specific error: you're most likely missing an NTFS-3G compression plugin. It's not clear what your distro is but in Fedora the package is called `ntfs-3g-system-compression`. According to repology it's not even available in Ubuntu and its derivatives, so you might want to install it manually:

https://github.com/ebiggers/ntfs-3g-system-compression

Comment: You are correct -- for these files, the "Size on Disk" is a lot less than its size.  Is there a way to, rather than installing a plug-in, to permanently un-compress them?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't even bother messing around with windows file systems. The cleanest job is to just copy the whole windows partition with `dd` to a new patririon on your new hard disk.

In fact, if the new disk is of equal or larger size, then don't even worry about partitions -- just copy with `dd` the whole raw disk, and after that, you can easily expand the partition(s) on the new hard disk, as you desire.

Comment: Yeah, but in my case the new disk is smaller...  Well, I believe I'll back up the contents, do `dd` anyways, and restore the files that get cut off.  See how that goes...

Comment: @Alex: If your the new disk is smaller, then disregard the second suggestion about raw disk. But still, your new disk is at least big enough to take the windows partition as it is, right? -- If that's not correct either, then there are some things you could do to shrink the existing partition, and then still copy it one-to-one with `dd`

Comment: I am working on shrinking the partition right now, and believe I can get it to fit onto the disk.  Why not `dd` if the new disk is smaller, though?

Comment: The disk can be smaller than the original, but it can't be smaller than the size of the partition you're trying to put on it. -- Example, original disk was 2TB, but the windows partition  was occupying only 900GB of it -- you can fit that onto your new 1TB disk, properly partitioned.

Comment: > "Why not dd if the new disk is smaller, though?"

It's sill going to be `dd`, but on partitions (if it fits), not on raw hard disks.

Comment: I mean, will something bad happen if I do `dd` on the whole disk?  Because that's what my plan right now is, to make sure that Windows can still boot, as per @Artem's advice.  Strange that the resizing has taken 3 hours already, and still not done...

Comment: @Alex: Yes, "`dd` on the whole disk" would be the best thing to do, provided the new disk is at least as large as the old disk. Otherwise, where is the rest of the old disk going go go? You'll be obviously losing all the stuff that doesn't fit. So how is this even a question?

Comment: @Pourko I see two problems with copying the whole disk if the new disk isn't the exact same size than the old disk. First of all, if the disk is partitioned using the GPT scheme (which is more or less the norm these days), the old disk contains a backup partition table at the end of the disk. If the new disk is larger, then the backup partition table ends up in the wrong place. Secondly, if the new disk is substantially larger, a lot of disk space is wasted.

Comment: @Johan Myréen: No, nothing will be "wasted", because as I said earlier, you can then easily expand the partition. Well, "easily" -- subjective -- for me I'd rather do that than deal with ntfs stuff.